# Inscribed Circles in Triangles

Tags: geometry, circles

This question appeared in this year's UNSW Maths competition. It was question 5b and it was the only question that i couldn't do. Sorry if my explanation is bad as it is complicated to understand without a diagram.

In part a) you are given that the radius of a inscribed circle in any triangle is:
$\displaystyle \frac{2s}{a+b+c}$   where $s$ is the area of the triangle and $a, b$ and $c$ are the length of the sides of the triangle.

So the question is:

If there is a triangle, the altitude is drawn so that there is $2$ triangles now. Now, the altitude is drawn again for each of the $2$ triangles, so that there is $4$ triangles. This process is down $2014$ times in total, so there is $2^{2014}$ triangles in the original triangle. Now, a circle is inscribed in each triangle so that there are $2^{2014}$ circles.

What is the fraction of the area of the circle over the area of the original triangle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "altitude" instead of "perpendicular bisector"? A perpendicular bisector doesn't always separate a triangle into two triangles, but an altitude does.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i meant altitude, not perpendicular bisector

Comment: Do you understand the question, or do you want me to explain it again.

Comment: 3rd row from below: I think you meant to say "$2^{2014}$ circles".

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Comment: Actually, I should've been more clear in my comment: There's always *at least one* altitude that separates a triangle into two triangles. (For an obtuse triangle, there's only one.)

Comment: Your question asks about "the area of **the circle**". Do you mean "the circles", as in "the total area of all of the circles"?

Comment: Yeah, so that fraction of the total area of the circles over the area of the original triangle.

Comment: Would the original triangle happen to be a *right* triangle?

Comment: No, it is a scalene triangle.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** After the first attitude, the triangles are divided into two groups containing of similar (right) triangles. The ratio of the areas of the corresponding circles to the triangles are the same for all triangles in a group.

**Note:** If the original triangle happens to be a *right* triangle as @Blue mention, there's no need to divide the $2^{2014}$ triangles into two groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you please explain how the 2 triangles are similar to each other.

Comment: Also, does the answer happen to be half.

Comment: After the first attitude, you have $2$ right triangles. Now if you divide a right triangle into $2$ smaller triangles by a attitude (to the hypotenuse), then each sub-triangle is similar to the big one. I don't see the answer being a half unless the original triangle is special.

Comment: I have tried do this question by using the similar triangles however i still not able to solve it. Could you please explain further how to do his question. Thanks.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to do this question. Thanks